# Is it ok to expose JpaRepository in Spring to clients?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a conceptual OO question about the usage of JpaRepository in Spring. Is it ok to just expose JpaRepository to the caller and let them call CRUD methods on that instance, or I have to wrap each method and only call corresponding JpaRepository methods from within the service?

In code:

```
public interface MyJpa extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long>
```

then:

```
@Repository
public class MyDbService{

    @Autowired
    private MyJpa myJpa;

    public Iterable<MyEntity> findAll()
    {
        return myJpa.findAll()
    }

    ... other CRUD methods

}
```

then client would do:

```
Iterable<MyEntity> entities = myDbService.findAll();
```

As opposed to:

```
@Repository
public class MyDbService{

    @Autowired
    private MyJpa myJpa;

    public MyJpa getJpa() {
        return myJpa 
    };
}
```

then client would do:

```
Iterable<MyEntity> entities = myDbService.getJpa().findAll();
```

What would be the main concern for not using the second approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer the latter approach. In the applications that I work on, I normally have the following layers (there may be more or fewer layers - this is a very rough guideline):

**Layer 1 - the client layer**

Perhaps a Spring MVC `@Controller` or a `@Service`. Eg:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
  @Autowired private MyManager myManager; // see Layer 2
}
```

**Layer 2 - the business layer**

Layer 2 provides separation between the client layer and the DAOs. It is generally a facade over 1 or more DAOs. You can put business logic/rules in here, or delegate, or add another layer. Eg:

```
@Component
public class MyManagerImpl implements MyManager {
  @Autowired private MyDao myDao; // see layer 3
}
```

**Layer 3 - the DAO layer**

Layer 3 are your DAO or `@Repository` classes. As per your example:

```
public interface MyDao extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long> {
  // Spring Data JPA magic here!
}
```

Some general words of advice:

- There are no strict rules, each application is different. Do what makes sense to you in the context of your application's requirements
- Each layer should only have the one responsibility. If you find a layer with multiple responsibilities (eg data-access and client API) then it may be better split into two

Finally, one minor change I'd make in your example is to annotation `MyDbService` with `@Component` rather than `@Repository`. `@Repository` should be limited to DAOs only.

Hope the rambling made sense!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, in terms of layers I do pretty much the same thing. My question is probably more about how opaque your layers are. I.e., can Layer 1 _only_ call APIs from Layer 2, or Layer 1 can obtain instance of Layer 3 from Layer 2 and then interact with it. Looks like violation of this inter-layer isolation could be one of the reasons for not using getJpa() approach.

Comment: @DennisK Yes, I always keep Layers 1 and 3 separate! It's definitely a violation of the responsibility per layer principle. Interestingly, this is the kind of thing I run into occasionally with Spring and auto-wiring. It's just too easy to obtain an instance of any Spring-managed class.

Answer (score 2):

The intermediate layer is obsolete in your case. If you're only re-exposing the dependency (which is an anti-pattern anyway) or find yourself doing anything but delegating to the dependency, just inject the dependency into you're client. So e.g. I think it might be absolutely okay to use the repository from a SpringMVC controller or the like.

However there are two things to consider:

1. We generally don-#t recommend to extend `JpaRepository` as it exposes JPA specific methods and the client shouldn't actually be aware of the underlying persistence technology. So rather use `CrudRepository`, `PagingAndSortingRepository` or the like.
2. Definitely *do* use an intermediate layer in case you need to orchestrate multiple calls and thus probably need to demarcate broader transaction boundaries. Or if you want to avoid clients to use the repository directly, make it package protected and higher level methods in a service, that might execute additional business functionality (e.g. password encoding, etc.)

Comment: Thanks, Oliver. Yes, this approach would work, but only if you have one client for your repository. Also great point in #1.

Comment: Actually what led me to this question is thinking about the service that combines several interlinked tables (say A, B and C), and in addition to CRUD exposes only a few specific methods like "get B.name by A.id and by C.timestamp". Re-mapping CRUD methods would've made this class a container for a lot of boilerplate code. So letting CRUD methods be accessible via myDbService.getACRUD(), .getBCRUD(), .getCCRUD() and then only add specific complex requests to the service itself could make the class much more concise and readable...